# Java 8 streams: Handle null values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Following code is throwing NPE for the property Salary being null.
class Person has properties: string: name, Integer: age, Integer: salary
`salary` can be null here. I want to create a List of salaries.

`persons.stream().mapToDouble(Person::getSalary).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Here I must retain null values in the result list. null can not be replaced with 0.

Comment: Why not just `map(...)` to `Double`, taking `null` into account as appropriate?

Comment: *Here I must retain* what possible could you do with more nulls? Unless  retain should be remove

Comment: @HadiJ Would `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` filter all the objects with any null property?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav of course not

Comment: Not sure why it has been downvoted.

Comment: You first need to read the stack trace of the exception, as always. What causes it? Is the value null? Does getProperty() throw it? Is it a bug in that method? Is it a bug in the code you posted? What is the desired outcome? Start by answering all these questions. It's been downvoted because you didn't bother posting the stack trace and the relevant code, making your question unclear, and because it doesn't seem you've tried anything to fix the error by yourself.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav The reason your question got downvoted is because you did no(t enough) research. [How much research effort is expected on SO? A lot.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) I found the duplicate with a google search, showing up as the topmost answer.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - the OP wants to **retain** nulls, not filter them out.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for the shoutout. But I did research before the asking the question. I must have spent more time on explaining the issue properly.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks. Appreciate your support. People are posting their solutions without even reading the question completely. They just read the first line `NPE`, filter the null objects. Issue is not with the null objects but the null property which is being cast to null.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav this is not about us, but about you and the way you posted the question. A clear example to begin with would have made it a good question - which you have not provided

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you could use `map` instead of `mapToDouble` along with the ternary operator:

```
List<Double> salaries = persons.stream()
    .map(Person::getSalary)
    .map(s -> s == null ? null : s.doubleValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: or `persons.stream()
    .map(p->(p.getProperty()!= null)?new Double(p.getProperty()):null)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @HadiJ calling `getProperty()` twice doesn’t look like an improvement to me. Further, you should never use `new Double(…)`, use either auto-boxing or `Double.valueOf`. Starting with Java 9, the constructor has been marked as deprecated to remind you on this. If you want a single `map` step, you can use `.map(p -> Optional.ofNullable(p.getSalary()).map(Integer::doubleValue).orElse(null))` but I’d prefer the code of this answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to convert each property value to `Double` if it's non-`null`, or leave it as `null` if it's `null`.  So just say so:

```
Integer prop = value.getProperty();
return (prop != null) ? prop.doubleValue() : null;
```

You can express that as a lambda, and pass it to `map()`.  (Left as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: I am not very familiar with stream's syntax. How would I use `value.getProperty()` in the map?